# File download with token - Secure [directory] files with nonces

Tags: file, download, token

I don't know the name of this technique but I'll describe as I saw and understand it.

At first, it's used to protect file on the server.

For example, this is a link for a PDF file, http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~jaseem/pub/L3_WLAN.pdf , I can download it easily.

Let's try now to download this file on http://av.vimeo.com/91289/159/66395917.mp4

The server responds an error : `An error occurred while processing your request. Reference #50.2c1b434d.1332206487.dadf1f`

So to download the MP4 file, I must have a token like this : 1332206979_99377a4999e218448c89adce520781db

Then trying now this link with the token on URL, I can download it easily.
http://av.vimeo.com/91289/159/66395917.mp4?token=1332206979_99377a4999e218448c89adce520781db

> My questions is how can I do to protect or secure files on my server and allow people to download them if they have a code or a token???

Comment: Generate a nonce. Give out the nonce. Forget the nonce once downloading starts.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, the token below lasts for a day in seconds.

```
<input  type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo nonce('token'); ?>" />

function nonce($expires=86400, $str){ // generates a secure nonce
    return sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i',ceil(time()/$expires)*$expires).$str.$salt);
}
```

Comment: This is a solution! But I want to secure more my files. For example this file isn't accessible without token http://av.vimeo.com/91289/159/66395917.mp4
Let us change the name of the file,  the server still prohibiting me to access the file and shows an error. It's a way to protect files from external access but it's possible for an application to read file on condition there's a token.

Comment: i have an idea... why not deny from all using an htaccess in your file repository, lets say /files/. then when requests are made for files it goes through /download.php but your php engine still has access to the file repository... i mean from there you would just have to mirror the binary and set the headers and viola.